# Nexus 4 factory reset, does it wipe/erase all the content?

Tags: nexus-4, factory-reset

Does factory reset erase/wipe the entire 'important data' on the phone? Such as password, sms, pictures, apps etc?
I used encase to check the internet storage and as it seems it's filled with zeros but not the entire phone, I can still see some data. 
Can i somehow restore the 'important data'?

best regards!

Answer (score 1):

### You want to sell your phone

Factory reset generally doesn't erase anything on a micro-SD card.

It doesn't in all cases exhaustively overwrite internal flash either. So it may be possible for determined people to [recover your data](http://blog.avast.com/2014/07/09/android-foreniscs-pt-2-how-we-recovered-erased-data/) (e.g. on a second-hand phone). This doesn't mean it is easy to do or 100% successful.

I believe since Android 4.3, a factory reset will attempt to more effectively wipe all data in the phone's internal storage.

Several sources advise using the phone's options to encrypt all data before doing a factory reset.

Some phones have a recovery mode accessed using [VolumeDown+Power](http://www.gadgetreview.com/2013/05/how-to-factory-reset-your-android-device) from which you can select "wipe data".

--

### You didn't realise Factory Reset might make your data inaccessible

If you don't regularly back-up important data, you will eventually lose it. You should also back up data before performing any major operation like a factory reset on any device/computer.

See links above for data recovery.